# How to ManyToMany and OneToMany in Symfony and Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I find the documentation very poor when it comes to explaining the creation of relationships between entities. So, i'll have to ask for help to my fellow StackExchangers. So, i'm trying to build the following cases:

**Case 1**

A `User` belongs to one or more `Group`, and a `Group` can have many `Permission`. A `User` also can have a `Permission`.

**Case 2**

A `Ticket` has a `Category`, multiple `Tag` and multiple `Comment`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure thing. First thing to understand is that there is no "one way" to do this. Doctrine gives a lot of flexibility in terms of how you [define the relationship](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) - even if multiple definitions produce the exact same DDL (and this is important to understand - some of the mapping choices only effect the object-side of the ORM, not the model-side)

Here's your Users/Groups/Permissions example, which are actually all many-to-many associations (I excluded all non-relevant but required code, like PK column definition)

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
  /**
   * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $groups
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_group",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  protected $groups;

  /**
   * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $permissions
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_permission",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  protected $permissions;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->permissions = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Group
{
  /**
   * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $permissions
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="group_has_permission",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  protected $permissions;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->permissions = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Permission {}
```

If you have questions about what's going on here, let me know.

Now, to your second example

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ticket
{
  /**
   * Many-To-One, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var Category
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $category;

  /**
   * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $permissions
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tickt_has_tag",
   *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
   *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
   * )
   */
  protected $tags;

  /**
   * One-To-Many, Bidirectional
   *
   * @var ArrayCollection $comments
   *
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="ticket")
   */
  protected $comments;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
  }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Comment
{
  /**
   * Many-To-One, Bidirectional
   *
   * @var Ticket $ticket
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  protected $ticket=null;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag {}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category {}
```

As before, let me know if you want any of this explained.

P.S. None of this was actually tested, I just kinda banged it out in my IDE real fast. There might be a typo or two ;)

Comment: Also, why different table names? And should'nt permission_id be declared?

Comment: @vinnylinux - I don't totally get your questions. inverseJoinColumns is just how you declare a unidirectional many-to-many relationship - there's no "why" to answer - that's just how it's done. And I don't get what your 2nd question is about at all.

Comment: Hey @vinnylinux, sorry it's taken me a while to get back with you. Been on vacation for a couple weeks.  Which example would you like to see getters/setters for? #1 or #2?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i got Doctrine to generate them. I didn't know it was able to do it. Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: The TicketCategory isn't missing something? Maybe an inversedby? Because it doesnt seem to work! I'm getting an exception: The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proxies\__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\TicketCategory to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

Comment: Hi, I was looking for oneToMany sample and the first results in google is this question here. So may I ask you to add for people like me, just a quick sample (or maybe a link) of a sample of oneToMany? And what are the other steps to have it working (e.g. command line with `php app/console doctrine:xxxx`) or does it work "on the fly"? Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Class User {  
 /**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="path\to\group", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
  */
  private $group;
```

You will have One to Many relation between `User` and `Group`.. The `targetEntity` is the path to the Entity that you want have a relationship with, the `mappedBy` is the variable from the `Group` Entity.  `cascade` means `User` can add to `Group` and remove from `Group`

Class Group {

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="path\to\user, inversedBy="group")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

This is the reserve side of the relationship.. `targetEntity` should have the path back to the parent entity, which is `User` in this case. `inversedBy` is the variable from the `User` Entity. `JoinColumn` is just telling Doctrine what to join on, this is automatically done if you don't set it yourself.