# symfony doctrine relational tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relational

I have `Students`, `Classrooms` and `Student_Classroom` tables.

`Students`:

```
 - ID  
 - Name  
 - Year_born
```

`Classroom`:

```
 - ID  
 - Name  
 - Number  
 - Floor
```

`Student_Classroom`:

```
 - ID
 - ID_Student
 - ID_Classroom
```

How should it be done using Symfony2 and Doctrine? Using annotations.

Comment: What have your tried? Have you set up any entities jet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a very simple `n:m` relation to me. Therefore your 2 entities should look something like this:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Student
{
    /** 
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Classroom")
     */
    private $classrooms;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->classrooms = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Classroom
{
    /** 
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Student")
     */
    private $students;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->students = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Make sure you add the required `use` statements to the top of both **entity class files**. Doctrine will automatically generate the `n:m` join table itself and handle all needed relations. Read more about `n:m` relations in the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#mapping-defaults). Also checkout [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319242/1847340).